# Monit lists Apache as Not Monitored

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, monit

I've just installed and configured monit according to [the monit documentation](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/MonitorApacheStatus).  All services apart from Apache are listed as Running, but Apache says **Not Monitored**.

The relevant lines in monit's config are:

```
check process apache with pidfile /var/run/httpd.pid
        group www
        start program = "/etc/init.d/httpd start"
        stop program = "/etc/init.d/httpd stop"
        if failed host localhost port 80
        protocol http then restart
        if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

I can access http://localhost/server-status and http://localhost fine from the server.  Monit lists Monitoring mode for Apache as *active*.

Server is running CentOS 5.4.

PID file is correct for parent httpd server:

```
[server ~]$ cat /var/run/httpd.pid
2905
[server ~]$ ps auxc | grep httpd
root      2905  0.0  0.9  26952  4808 ?        Ss   11:36   0:00 httpd
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure the contents of the pid file match up with the Apache master process's pid (i.e., the `httpd` process that runs as root).  It's possible the pid file is stale.

If it's stale, get the pid of the Apache master process, and do something like `echo 1234 > /var/run/httpd.pid`, where `1234` is the pid in question.

After that, run `monit monitor apache` to restart monitoring of that service.

Comment: The PID file was correct, but running `monit monitor apache` got it started, and now it seems to be working fine after restarting the service.  I should also have tried clicking the Enable Monitor button on the web interface.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide the OS version/distribution, but on CentOS 6, the PID file you should be monitoring is located at: `/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid`

So change to:

```
check process apache with pidfile /var/run/httpd/httpd.pid
```

Incidentally, CentOS 5 has the Apache PID file in: `/var/run/httpd.pid`

Edit: Also quote the PID path.

There's a note on the Monit mailing list about the protocol test you're using:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/monit-general/2004-12/msg00057.html

You may need to pass a hostname or site name if you're using name-based virtual hosts.

Comment: It's CentOS 5.4.  PID file is correct.

Comment: Using your config on a CentOS 5 server, I get `Process 'apache'
  status                            Does not exist
  monitoring status                 monitored`

Comment: Where are you seeing that output?

Comment: You should quote your pidfile path "/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid". Also see the note I placed in the initial answer about a possible need for a VirtualHosts directive.

Comment: Makes no difference quoted or not.

Comment: Making a request to http://localhost works fine.  I'm not getting Connection Failed - I'm getting "Not Monitored".